# Add an element to the array

Tags: javascript

I have a data array like this,

```
tourGuide: [
    {"location": "london"},
    {"location": "paris"},
    {"location": "frankfurt"}
]
```

I want to rewrite the `tourGuide` so that it will contain the indices too. so it will become something like:

```
tourGuide: [
    {"location": "london", "index":0},
    {"location": "paris", "index":1},
    {"location": "frankfurt","index":2}
]
```

I tried this:

```
var x, l=0;
for(x in tourGuide){
    tourGuide["index"] = l;
    l++;
}
```

but that may not be right approach.

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  If you decide to change the order of the elements how are you going to keep up with the index?  If you want to get the object from the array you need to know the index *anyway*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var x, l=0;

for(x in tourGuide){

tourGuide[x]["index"] = l;
l++;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for(var i=0;i<tourGuide.length;i++){
    tourGuide[i].index=i
}

//----or more simplified...----

var i=0;
for(;i<tourGuide.length;){
    tourGuide[i].index=i++
}
```

**LIVE DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/DerekL/qvdzR/

But actually, you don't really have to create an `index`, since they are in an array, they *already* have an `index` value.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you forget about the `location` property and just make a simple array. Unless you intend to add more properties later, a regular array will supply the numeric index for you. Just do:

```
var output = array();
for (var i=0; i<tourGuide.length; i++) {
  // Just stick each of the locations onto a plain old array
  output.push(tourGuide[i].location;
}

console.log(output);
```